# Getting "Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined", while loading "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, object-detection, image-recognition

I'm developing an application in React Native, the primary purpose of which is to select a video from a gallery and run an object detection model on it. I'm currently using a TensorFlow model named "coco-ssd".

According to their [Docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd#via-npm), I first need to load the model before proceeding. However, I've encountered an issue here: when I attempt to load the model, it throws the error, "Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined". Here is my code: -

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, SafeAreaView, View} from 'react-native';
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import * as cocossd from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [videoUri, setVideoUri] = useState(null);

  const loadCocoModel = async () => {
    try {
      await tf.ready();
      console.log('Tensorflow ready');
      const model = await cocossd.load();
      console.log('Handpose model loaded.');
      detect(model);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCocoModel();
  }, []);

  const detect = (model: cocossd.ObjectDetection) => {
    console.log('TODO: implement detect');
  };

  const selectVideo = async () => {
    try {
      const response: any = await launchImageLibrary({
        mediaType: 'video',
      });
      if (!response.didCancel && response.assets.length > 0) {
        setVideoUri(response.assets[0].uri);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: '100%',
        }}>
        <Button title="Select Video" onPress={selectVideo} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am hoping for a solution or recommendation to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.